# how to set "xhost +" comand on start on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have to run a grafic application on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
All works greate, but every time I boot the pc, I must run "xhost +" comand on terminal to execute the application.
There is a solution to avoid to tipe this comand everty time?

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I have found the solution. If someone could be interested, this is my solution: My problem was that at every reboot I had to run the "xhost +" comand. So I created a script with this line and I put it in the Startup Applications. Now works:)

Bye